# Direcx 9 Camera Setup

Tags: directx

I was configuring my camera setup under directx9 and what i achieved is to be able to view 180 degrees,but i couldn't reach 360.Here is the Code:

```
float x = 0;
float y = 0;
float z = 10;
float dx = 0;
float dy = 0;
void FreeMotion()
{
    if(::GetAsyncKeyState('W') )
    {
        z -= 0.3;
    }
    if(::GetAsyncKeyState('S') )
    {
        z += 0.3;
    }
    if(::GetAsyncKeyState('A') )
    {
        x += 0.7;
    }
    if(::GetAsyncKeyState('D') )
    {
        x -= 0.1;
    }
    if(::GetAsyncKeyState('R') )
    {
        y += 0.1;
    }
    if(::GetAsyncKeyState('F') )
    {
        y -= 0.1;
    }
    if(::GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) )
    {
        dx -= 0.1;
    }
    if(::GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) )
    {
        dx += 0.1;
    }
    if(::GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) )
    {
        dy += 0.1;
    }
    if(::GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) )
    {
        dy -= 0.1;
    }
}
void render()
{

    d3ddev->Clear(0,NULL,D3DCLEAR_TARGET,D3DCOLOR_XRBG(0,0,0),1.0,0);
    d3ddev->BeginScene();
FreeMotion();
        D3DXMATRIX View;
        D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&View,&D3DXVECTOR3(x,y,z),&D3DXVECTOR3(x+dx,y+dy,z-10),&D3DXVECTOR3(0,1,0));
        d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW,&View);
```

...

So this piece of code give me the ability to move around but not to look behind!
can some one tell me how to make it look in a full 360 degrees ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it makes more sense to interpret `dx` and `dy` as rotation angles. Then you would calculate the view target as:

```
target = (x, y, z) + (sin(dx) * cos(dy), sin(dy), -cos(dx) * cos(dy))
```

Update this calculation in your `D3DXMatrixLookAtLH` call and you should get 360°.

Comment: D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&matView,&D3DXVECTOR3(x,y,z),&D3DXVECTOR3(x+(sin(dx) * cos(dy)),y+sin(dy),-cos(dx)*cos(dy)),&D3DXVECTOR3(0,1,0));  If this is what you mean,then it didn't work.I got a shaky camera.

Comment: That's what I meant. Except that you missed the `z` in the last component of the target. What do you mean by shaky? You may need to adapt the update step size. `0.1` may be two much depending on the update frequency.